# How to `switch` the content by condition

Tags: angularjs

In my `ng-repeat`, i require the `DOM` to be switched, according to the `active` status.

i tried like this, but not working for me:

```
<ul>

    <li ng-click="activate(item)" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{active : active == item}">

          <span ng-if="item==active"> 
            <span>{{item}}</span><!-- when active nested under span -->
          </span>
          <!-- else without nesting the span -->
          <span ng-if="item== !active">{{item}}</span> //this is not working

    </li>

  </ul>
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/kF5s39eKjqyhC6NE7O9G?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your last `ng-if` statement to this (you've just made syntax error):

```
<span ng-if="item !== active">{{item}}</span>
```

Your `active` variable isn't boolean, so you can't toggle it in your statement.